# updating user in test function

Tags: django, unit-testing

I am facing an issue with a failure while trying to update an instance of worker in test function. Each time I try to transmit worker data in post method like:

response = self.client.post(url, worker_2)

it fails to update
in my case I just change an email.

In a debugger terminal it displays a mistake like "two password field didn't match". But it's very strange because I didn't transfer 2 password within input data, just initially retreiving worker from database with existing password, changing email, and transferring this data as inputs in post method.

And so it showed that this field "email" was not changed.

How can I effectively fix this problem?

I tried to drop password after retreiving a worker from database and then set "password1" + "password2" for this worker. But unfortunately it didn't work.

I have no any clear idea what actions can I undertake else to achieve a result - to update this object.